# How do I subtract columns of different tables containing different number of rows?

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have to similar tables

Table 1

| code | value |
| --- | --- |
| 0.00001 | 3 |
| 0.00002 | 4 |
| 0.00003 | 1 |

Table 2

| code | value |
| --- | --- |
| 0.00001 | 2 |
| 0.00002 | 5 |

And I have different number of rows in both tables. When I used 'DIFFERENCE' function I'm only getting the the difference for 1st 2 rows and the 3rd row is not displayed. And also I don't just want to get the difference but also + or - values just like subtraction. How do I do it?

I tried this

```
SELECT t1.Code, 
      (t1.value-t2.value) AS DIFFERENCE
FROM TABLE1 t1
INNER JOIN TABLE2 t2 on t1.code = t2.value
```

| code. | DIFFERENCE |
| --- | --- |
| 0.00001 | 1 |
| 0.00002 | -1 |
| 0.00003 | 1 |

Comment: `on t1.code = t2.value` Does that seem odd to you?

Answer (score 2):

Use a left join from the first to second table, which will prevent codes from being dropped in the first table.

```sql
SELECT t1.code, t1.value - COALESCE(t2.value, 0) AS DIFFERENCE
FROM TABLE1 t1
LEFT JOIN TABLE2 t2 ON t1.code = t2.value
ORDER BY t1.code;
```

You might need a full outer join here:

```sql
SELECT COALESCE(t1.code, t2.code) AS code,
       COALESCE(t1.value, 0) - COALESCE(t2.value, 0) AS DIFFERENCE
FROM TABLE1 t1
FULL OUTER JOIN TABLE2 t2 ON t1.code = t2.value
ORDER BY COALESCE(t1.code, t2.code);
```

Comment: Does this condition work for the other table too? I mean if there are more number of rows in 2nd table than 1st table.

Comment: @NesaraMN Use a full outer join, q.v. my updated answer.